# Implement sqrt method using the approximation approach. Cannot exit loop even the condition is false

Tags: java, infinite-loop, square-root

I am so close to complete my practical question, just stuck at don't know why I cannot exit the loop after getting correct result.

The question ask to implement sqrt method using the approximation approach.

1. Let `num` is the number to apply sqrt method.
2. For the `num> 1`, `lowerLimit = 1` and `upperLimit = number`
3. Then find the `midpoint` of `lowerLimit` and `upperLimit` which is `(lowerLimit+upperLimit)/2`
4. Square the `midpoint`, `squareMidpoint = Math.pow(midpoint, 2)`
5. If the `squareMidpoint > num`, `upperLimit = midpoint`, else `lowerLimit= midpoint`.
6. Repeat third step again until get num with 8 significant digits.

**From step 1 to step 5, I think I did correctly since the output is correct.**

I actually don't understand step 6 well.

**My problem is if the `num = 4`, the program keep printing `2` forever.**

Here is my code:

```
import java.lang.Math; 
public class p2q4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //Implement the sqrt method using the approximation approach
        
        //initialized lowerLimit and upperLimit
        double lowerLimit = 0, upperLimit = 0;
        
        //num is the number to square root.
        double num = 5;
        
        //For number greater than one,
        if (num > 1) {
            lowerLimit = 1; //lower limit to one
            upperLimit = num; //upper limit to the number
        }

        double squareMidpoint;
        double midpoint;

        do {
            //Determine the midpoint between the lower and upper limits
            midpoint = (lowerLimit + upperLimit) / 2;
            
            //Evaluate the square of the midpoint
            squareMidpoint = Math.pow(midpoint, 2);

            //If the square of the midpoint is greater than the number
            if (squareMidpoint > num) {
                //upper limit to the midpoint
                upperLimit = midpoint;
            } else {
                //lower limit to the midpoint
                lowerLimit = midpoint;
            }
            
            //for debugging purpose
            System.out.printf("midpoint=%f  squareMidpoint=%f upperLimit=%f lowerLimit=%f upperLimit/lowerLimit=%f\n", midpoint, squareMidpoint, upperLimit, lowerLimit, upperLimit/lowerLimit);

          
        //even though upperLimit/lowerLimit is '1' but still keep looping
        } while (upperLimit/lowerLimit != 1); //I not sure this condition is correct.
        
        //Output
        System.out.printf("x = %.0f, root = %f\n", num, midpoint);
    }
}
```

Here is my practical question:

> Instead of using the sqrt method in the Math class, you have been
> asked to implement the sqrt method using the approximation approach
> described below:
>
> For numbers greater than one, the square root method must initially
> set a lower limit to one and an upper limit to the number (since the
> square root of the number always lies between one and the number).
>
> It must then determine the midpoint between the lower and upper limits
> and evaluate the square of the midpoint. If the square of the midpoint
> is greater than the number, the square root method must move the upper
> limit to the midpoint and similarly if the square of the midpoint is
> less than the number, it must move the lower limit to the midpoint.
>
> After moving the appropriate limit, the square root method must
> evaluate a new midpoint and repeat the process until the desired
> precision is obtained.
>
> The required precision for double precision floating point numbers is
> 8 significant digits. The precision at any iteration can be determined
> by dividing the difference between the limits by the lower limit.
>
> When this is less than 1/108 any number between the limits will be an
> estimate of the square root of the number to the required precision.
> To minimize the error, the square root method should return the
> midpoint between the final limits that satisfy the precision
> requirement.
>
> The square root method must return exact values for the special cases
> of zero and one.
>
> If an application attempts to calculate the square root of a negative
> number, the square root method should display an appropriate message
> and terminate the program.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In your code where `System.out.printf("midpoint=%f  squareMidpoint=%f upperLimit=%f lowerLimit=%f upperLimit/lowerLimit=%f\n", midpoint, squareMidpoint, upperLimit, lowerLimit, upperLimit/lowerLimit);
` Are you ever getting upperLimit equal to lowerLimit?

Comment: ya upperLimit will equal to lowerLimit

Comment: The output is like this


midpoint=2.236068  squareMidpoint=5.000000 upperLimit=2.236068 lowerLimit=2.236068 upperLimit/lowerLimit=1.000000

midpoint=2.236068  squareMidpoint=5.000000 upperLimit=2.236068 lowerLimit=2.236068 upperLimit/lowerLimit=1.000000

midpoint=2.236068  squareMidpoint=5.000000 upperLimit=2.236068 lowerLimit=2.236068 upperLimit/lowerLimit=1.000000

Comment: It is not equal to 1.. it is actually equal to 1.00000, this might be your problem, you are comparing a float number to integer, which could give you wrong results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print `upperLimit/lowerLimit` with more significant digits, you'll see that it gets as small as `1.0000000000000002`, but never reaches 1, which is why your loop never ends.

Instead of staying in the loop as long as:

```
upperLimit/lowerLimit != 1
```

you should change the condition to:

```
while (upperLimit - lowerLimit > 0.0000000001)
```

which will exit the loop when the limits get close enough to each other.

That's what step #6 means by "8 significant digits" - your approximation should get the first 8 significant digits correct.

Comment: OMG! You save my day! I have been solving this question for 5 hours!

Comment: @PaulFloyd In what way?

Comment: Do you know why my output `x = 1, root = 0.000000`?

Comment: @Coolwei It's due to `if (num > 1) {`. Change it to `if (num >= 1) {`

Comment: The test "upperLimit - lowerLimit > 0.000000001" is not sound. The problem with absolute tolerances like this is that if the inputs are very large, then the smallest difference is bigger than the tolerance and if the inputs are very small then all differences are smaller than the tolerance. So unless you know that the inputs are not many orders of magnitude different to 1, you need to introduce some relative tolerance.